# List array as one cell when using .writerow()

Tags: python, csv, file-io, export-to-csv, opencsv

Write to CSV:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'WOW', '['HMM', 'WOW']', 'BYE'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Cool', 'Nice'])
```

Excel Output Unexpected:
[image]

Expected Excel Output:
[image]

How would I keep `['HMM', 'WOW']` all in cell C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that you are using a delimiter `,` but also trying to put that `,` into a cell. That's not gonna work. You can try using:

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```

And then change your OS regional settings, so your Office app would recognize `;` as a delimiter in spreadsheets. Otherwise, you have to get rid of `,` in a cell

Also, at least for me, it throws an error, cuz you didn't escape `'` symbol properly when defining your list. I had to change it to:

`spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'WOW', "['HMM', 'WOW']", 'BYE'])`

The result of using `;` as a delimiter:

[image]

Comment: Smart. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If that's all, you can accept my answer :)